# Как присвоить в имя первой переменной значение другой переменной?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код:

```
var a = "n";
var b = "текст";
var c = "текст2";
```

Как присвоить в имя переменной `b` и `с` значение переменной `a`?

Чтобы в итоге ответ был таким:

```
var bn = "текст";
var cn = "текст2";
```

Т.е. я присваиваю для переменной `a` какую-нибудь букву, а перемененные `b` и `с` автоматически будут иметь новое имя (благодаря присвоенному `a`).
Возможно ли так делать?

Comment: Невозможно, да и зачем? Используйте объект.

Comment: Никак - имя переменной это идентификатор, а не набор символов. Любая манипуляция бандлерами при сжатии, сразу сломала бы ваш код. Так как в итоге `let name` превратится в `let n или let $n` и тому подобное.

Comment: **window['a'] = "n"; window['b'] = "текст"; window['c'] = "текст2"; window['b' + a] = window.b; delete window.b; window['c' + a] = window.c; delete window.c;** - вот так можно добиться желаемого результата. Только так лучше не делать никогда и ни при каких обстоятельствах